# Static field with leak context

Tags: java, android, static

My code is

```
 // Asynctask class to handle load data from database in background
private class SyncGetLocations extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mPrgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mToolbarView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Get data from database
        getLocationDataFromDatabase(mSelectedId);
        return null;
    }
… etc
```

Android studio report that this Asynctask class should be static else leaks might occur.

When change to static get a lots of errors like non-static methods and fields cannot be referenced from a static context.

I added:

```
MyActivity myactivity = new MyActivity();
myactivity.mPrgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
…
```

all look nice until I run application and get error because I try to access void fields.

Advices?

Comment: Instead of using Asynctask to load database you can try other networking libraries such as Retrofit or Volley.

Comment: @DeepakS.Gavkar OP is loading from data database not server, I guess

Comment: Are  you using SQLite ? In that case @Nick you can use RxJava

Comment: `new MyActivity();` never create an instance of an Activty. Only system should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you make the inner class static you no longer have access to the Activity and its properties. One workaround would be to have a weak reference to your Activity inside the AsynkTask:

```
private static class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<YourActivity> activityReference;

    YourTask(YourActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return "task finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        YourActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;

        activity.myVariable = "example";

        TextView textView = activity.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Anyway I think that creating the AsyncTask as a top level class instead of as an inner class would also solve your problem (as an inner class you have the risk of the class being alive more time than it needs to because of the AsyncTask).

Comment: Well I've just tested it and it didn't get me that error, what are you passing when creating the AsyncTask? It should be your Activity

Comment: in async I try to show a progress dialog   activity.progressDialog .show(); but return next error: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:904) ...

Comment: The AsyncTask is not executed in the Main thread (that's it's main purpose), so you can't access the UI from the `doInBackground` method (if that's what you're trying to do). Also, in your question I see you're instantiating your Activity in a weird way. I don't know if that could be the source of your problem, maybe you should pass the activity reference using `this`

Comment: I figure out. Thanks for your patience!